# Surfaces that allow self-maps which are fixed point free

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was looking at the following problem:

For which connected compact surfaces $X$ without boundary does there exist a continuous map $f: X\rightarrow X$ with no fixed point?

There is also a hint to the problem which says the following:

Verify by inspection that if $\mathbb{Z}$ is a direct summand of $H_1(X)$, then $S^1$ is a retract of $X$.

I was having no idea on this problem, and even don't know how to derive the hint. The only thought that I have is that both $T^2$ and $S^2$ would allow such self-map, e.g. a rotation map on $T^2$, and antipodal map on $S^2$. I have no idea what happens to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ or the connected sums.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to construct a map whose fixed point set is a circle. Then compose it with a map from circle to circle with no-fixed point.

Comment: I would like to know who this  inspector is. Seems not so easy to me without obstruction theory (to even see, I think?)

Comment: You don't need obstruction theory. Just consider  q retraction from surface onto a circle ( think that the circle is on the surface). Now compose it with a map maybe a small rotation to kill off allthe fixed points.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I meant for the existence of such a retraction. I guess for the torus the retraction feels easy, but perhaps you are right, map $S^1$ to some free $\mathbb Z$ part of $\pi_1$.  Maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: IMHO, the easiest way to see this retraction exists is to do it in the polygon.

Comment: @SteveD ah that is perfect.